# Analytical coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have the following polynomial, 
$$f(x)=(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2+x^3)^2$$
expanding this gives: 
$$f(x)=1+4x+8x^2+12x^3+14x^4+12x^5+8x^6+4x^7+x^8$$
now suppose I want to extend this as follow: 
$$f(x)=(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)^{n-1}$$
where $n$ is a positive integers and can be odd/even, I wonder how to write the coefficients analytically in terms of $n$?

Comment: you have the geometric series in the second bracket

Comment: Writing coefficients in terms of $n$ and expressing $f(x)$ in closed form are two different things.  The comment above (+1) does the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Macavity indeed I need the coefficients in term of $n$.

Comment: I have edited the question.